# Optimizing calculation speed in python: multiprocessing or no?

Tags: python, optimization, multiprocessing

I'm trying to calculate the gravitational force from one cylinder on another, using python 3.6. To do this I divide each cylinder in point masses and then calculate the forces from each point mass in cylinder 1, on each point mass in cylinder 2. Of course I'd like to make these point masses as small as possible, but the number of computations increases very quickly. Therefore I'm trying to optimize my code.
It looks something like this

```
class Mass:
    def calcForceFrom(self, p_mass):
        F_total = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
        for i, element in enumerate(self.elements):
            p_mass.calcForceOn(element)
            F_total = F_total + element.sum_of_forces

        return F_total

    def calcForceOn(self, p_target):
        # calculates the force from this Mass on some point mass
        for element in self.elements:
            p_target.addForce(Mass.F(p_target, element))

    @staticmethod
    def F(p_target, p_element):
        # difference vector
        r = p_element.x - p_target.x

        # calculate length^3/2
        rr = (r.dot(r))**(3/2)

        return p_element.m * p_target.m / rr * r

F_12 = cyl1.calcForceFrom(cyl2)
```

I already used cProfiler, function F is called most often and takes up most of the time. I made some improvements to it and right now I don't think there's much more gains to be had.

So next I figured I could use multithreading to calculate the force on multiple elements at the same time. However, this did not help at all. Here's what I tried:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

class Mass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = ThreadPool(4)

    def calcForceFrom(self, p_mass):
        forces = self.pool.map(p_mass.calcForceOn, self.elements)
        F_total = sum(forces)
```

The computation time more than doubled using this method. I thought that making these calculations run in parallel would improve the speed. Apparently I was wrong.

So, why is this not working? What use cases should I use multiprocessing for? What other methods might there be for improving the speed of my calculation?

BTW: using the symmetry in the problem to reduce the number of points I need to calculate is already on my to-do list.

Comment: Did you read the docs (carefully)? I'm not that familiar with python's multiprocessing (but used the alternative wrapper joblib at least one time) and i would strongly assume that your pool.map is copying/serializing your data for each process (which might be costly).

Comment: `(r.dot(r))**(3/2)` I have seen that python is pretty slow for exponentiation compared to math libraries... In that case it might not be by much, but if F is called most often it might be worth investigating. As for the threading part, are you sure to have 4 cores available? Most of the times in VM you can have issues.

Comment: The hint is in the module name `multiprocessing.dummy` - it just simulates multiprocessing through the threading interface, and Python threads don't execute in parallel due to the dreaded GIL. In fact, as you've noticed, it will just make your code run slower. What amount of data are we talking about here and how many calculations do you expect per run?

Comment: If you really need high performance, it might be an idea to rewrite critical parts in C.

Comment: Only one thread ever runs at the same time, which allows concurrent processing, but not parallel processing (it's mostly cooperative multitasking, although there is a little preemptive multitasking also going on, but regardless, only one thread runs at any one time). The `multiprocessing` module allows true parallel processing on separate cores, but involves a lot of overhead (including the spawning of subprocesses each with their own Python interpreter). See [**_Grok the GIL_**](https://opensource.com/article/17/4/grok-gil). Bottom-line is I don't think either approach would be helpful.

Comment: @Fabien I am running the code on repl.it, mostly because it's easy to share with someone else who isn't familiar with coding very much. According to len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)) I have 4 cores available. You are correct about the exponention, that might save some more time.

Comment: @zwer: I don't know exactly how much points I'll need, but F might be called a few hundred million times. I need to experiment a bit with how much points are necessary for the accuracy I require.

Comment: Multiple *threads* use the same processor core; multiple *processes* use additional cores if available.  Multiple threads will not speed up a number-crunching application because they do not bring more computing resources to bear.   Multiple processes *do* bring more resources to bear and therefore can (in some cases) speed up CPU-bound programs. You are using multiprocessing.dummy, which always uses threads instead of processes.  There is no way that can speed up a program of this type.  Why do you import from `multiprocessing.dummy` instead of from `multiprocessing`?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I had no prior experience with multithreading or multiprocessing and did not really realize the difference. I just got that part from an example I found. I tried to implement multiprocessing in my code but it looks like I need to rework it from the start. Right now my program works, just a bit slower. I don't think it's worth it to invest much more time making it run faster. I'll do some experimenting with multiprocessing later.